# Backbone view with SVG <g> element not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js, svg

I am working on an application using Backbone and am having issues with a view for which the "el" property is a dynamically created `<g>` element.  The code for the view is as follows:

```
var DependencyLineView = Backbone.View.extend({

    //el: document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g'),

    initialize: function () {

        //var gElement = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g');
        //var gElementComplete = createShape(this.options.iteration, this.el);

        var gElement = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g');
        var gElementComplete = createShape(this.options.iteration, gElement);
        this.el = gElementComplete;

        $(gElementComplete).attr('stroke-width', '1px')
                           .attr('stroke', 'red')
                           .attr('fill', 'red');

        this.el = gElementComplete;
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        $('#lineContainer').append(this.el);
    },

    events: {
        "click": "clickEvent",
    },

    clickEvent: function(ev) {
        alert('here');
    },

});
```

If I generate the element during initialization (instead of using the "el" property), rendering occurs as expected (I.E. a `<g>` element is added to #lineContainer every time a new view is substantiated and rendered).  If I generate the element using the "el" property, however, only one `<g>` element is created no matter how many times I add a new view and render it.  I wrote an function called "createShape" for demonstration purposes that adds a few `<line>` elements to the SVG group elements.  Here are the results of both of the methods:

Generating element during initialization:

```
<svg id="lineContainer">
    <g stroke-width="1px" stroke="red">
        <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="50" y2="10"></line>
        <line x1="50" y1="10" x2="50" y2="50"></line>
        <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50"></line>
    </g>
    <g stroke-width="1px" stroke="red">
        <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="100" y2="20"></line>
        <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="100"></line>
        <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Generated using "el" property:

```
<svg id="lineContainer">
    <g stroke-width="1px" stroke="red" fill="red">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"></line>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"></line>
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="0"></line>
        <line x1="10" y1="10" x2="50" y2="10"></line>
        <line x1="50" y1="10" x2="50" y2="50"></line>
        <line x1="50" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50"></line>
        <line x1="20" y1="20" x2="100" y2="20"></line>
        <line x1="100" y1="20" x2="100" y2="100"></line>
        <line x1="100" y1="100" x2="200" y2="100"></line>
        <line x1="30" y1="30" x2="150" y2="30"></line>
        <line x1="150" y1="30" x2="150" y2="150"></line>
        <line x1="150" y1="150" x2="300" y2="150"></line>
        <line x1="40" y1="40" x2="200" y2="40"></line>
            <line x1="200" y1="40" x2="200" y2="200"></line>
            <line x1="200" y1="200" x2="400" y2="200"></line>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I want to be able to utilize the "el" property to dynamically generate the SVG group elements so that I can use the events delegated by backbone natively (and for number of other reasons, if not just to adhere to the backbone style of coding in JavaScript) but each group needs to be appended separately (not collapsed, as it's doing in the example).  What am I doing wrong?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2DJ8/1/

Comment: Why are you using Backbone 0.3.3? That's a stone age version of Backbone. I'm getting five `<g>`s inside `#lineContainer` from this version of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7P3DV/ (Backbone upgraded, switched to `setElement` instead of `this.el = ...`). I also see five `<g>`s with your original code. Is that not what is supposed to happen?

Comment: I used a JSFiddle backbone boilerplate but I'm getting the same results irregardless of the backbone version.  The JSFiddle will produce the correct result because the element is being generated in the initialize function, as opposed to using "el".  If you uncomment the 3 lines that are currently commented and attempt to render using "el" to dynamically generate the element, you'll see the issue I'm talking about.

Comment: Here's another JSFiddle that demonstrates the above: http://jsfiddle.net/c3uZ3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say this in your view:

```
el: document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g'),
```

You're attaching that `<g>` to the `el` in the view's prototype so all of the instances share a single `<g>` until, of course, you change the `el` inside `initialize`. However, before you assign a new `el`, you're doing this:

```
initialize: function () {
    var gElementComplete = createShape(this.options.iteration, this.el);
    // --------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^
```

Your `createShape` function will add things to its second argument and each time you create a new `DependencyLineView`, they're using the exact same `<g>` as their `el` when you call `createShape`: there isn't a distinct `el` for each instance of the view, they're all sharing exactly the same `<g>`.

There's really no reason to specify the `el` when creating your view "class" so don't bother, just create the `<g>` as needed and attach it to the view using [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement):

```
initialize: function (options) {
    var gElement = document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g');
    var gElementComplete = createShape(options.iteration, gElement);
    // ...
    this.setElement(gElementComplete);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zVfJb/

Note that I'm using `setElement` instead of directly assigning to `this.el`, never assign to `this.el` yourself as that won't bind the event handlers or set up the cached `this.$el`. Also note that I'm not using Backbone 0.3.3 for any of this as that's a stone age version of Backbone, I'm assuming that you're using at least 1.0. Using a more recent Backbone also means that `this.options` isn't automatically set up in views so I'm just using `options.iteration` and an explicit `options` argument to `initialize`.

If for some reason you insist on having an `el` in the view definition then make it a function so that every instance gets a distinct `<g>`:

```
el: function() {
    return document.createElementNS(nameSpace, 'g');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/GLbts/

That said, all of this render logic really should be inside your view's `render` method (that's what `render` is for, rendering); `render` also conventionally ends with `return this;` so you should do that too. Then ideally you'd say things like this:

```
var i, var v;
for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    v = new DependencyLineView({ iteration: i });
    $('#lineContainer').append(v.render().el); // this is why `render` returns `this`.
}
```

and your view wouldn't touch the DOM at all: it would just create the elements it needs and leave it up to the caller to put them somewhere.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This worked flawlessly!  It was essentially this.setElement() that I needed.  Your explanation of how and where to render these elements was really helpful as well!